# How to get some digits/characters from the end of a wordpress title and display them?

Tags: wordpress, get, character, title

The wordpress theme I am working on is portfolio styled and is being used as a product catalogue. The issue is that the price of each product is written at the end of the wordpress/post title like "Product Name - 100,00€" or "Product Name - 100€" and I want to get and display in a variable the price only like "100,00€" or "100€".

So I must detect and display only the numbers from the end.

Trimming from the begin of the title might work (counting the full length of the title and deleting the amount of the digits of the price but not all the prices have the same length :-P)

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The php functions you're looking for are `strrev`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

and `explode`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php